# Temporary burst of speed with chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm working on a game where you have to  watch out for a ball that bounces around the screen (bounces at the edges of the screen). I am using cocos2d together with chipmunk. In chipmunk I have defined 0 gravity and 0 friction, so that the bouncing ball keeps it's original speed after every bounce.

However, I want to introduce a special type of bouncing ball that gets a temporary speed boost for a couple of seconds and then return to it's original speed.

Is there a nice chipmunk way of doing this, a sort of temporary impulse that one can add? Or do I have to do it the long way manually, by storing the original speed and keeping track of how long (how many cycles) the boosted speed has been running and resetting the original speed at the end of the "boost" period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chipmunk doesn't provide timers and such like that, but Cocos2D does.

Comment: Thanks Slembcke. I guess it's the long way around then.. :-S